# How to make a jpg image semi transparent?

Tags: python, opencv

I want set alpha channel to a .jpg image and set its value to 0.5 or 50% or at 128 (0 to 1 total range or 0-255 range) and save it as .png using only opencv and numpy. I know how to do it using other libraries but we have been asked to perform the above question using only  two library i.e. import cv2 and import numpy. 
i have added the alpha channel but i do not know how to set its value to 50% transparency, please help as I am new to opencv-python.

I have tried this code but I am getting a black image even when I open it with paint.

[Reduce opacity of image using Opencv in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44320567/reduce-opacity-of-image-using-opencv-in-python)

this is how I have added my alpha

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('food.jpg')
bgra = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
print(bgra.shape)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python OpenCV - add alpha channel to RGB image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32290096/python-opencv-add-alpha-channel-to-rgb-image)

Comment: Please refer to the above answer and simply replace the `50` with `127` at the step I am creating the alpha channel.

Comment: It should be understood that JPEG format images can not have transparency. The image that is read into from a .jpg file can have transparency, but that is an OpenCV internal image. If that image is then written out to a .jpg file (i.e., in JPEG format), the transparency will be lost.To preserve transparency, the output file needs to be in a format that supports transparency, like PNG. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906144/transparent-background-in-jpeg-image/16906178

Comment: ZdaR, I have tried the above link but did not replace it with 127 then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several ways of doing this... I'll start with this image:

[image]

---

Add blank alpha channel with OpenCV and set content with Numpy indexing:

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np 
img = cv2.imread('paddington.jpg')

# Add alpha layer with OpenCV
bgra = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA) 

# Set alpha layer semi-transparent with Numpy indexing, B=0, G=1, R=2, A=3
bgra[...,3] = 127

# Save result
cv2.imwrite('result.png',bgra)
```

[image]

---

Alternatively, create a solid alpha layer filled with 128s and stack depth-wise with Numpy `dstack()`:

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np 
img = cv2.imread('paddington.jpg')

# Create solid alpha layer, same height and width as "img", filled with 128s
alpha = np.zeros([img.shape[0],img.shape[1],1], dtype=np.uint8) + 128

# Depth-wise stack that layer onto existing 3 RGB layers
bgra = np.dstack((img,alpha))

# Save result
cv2.imwrite('result.png',bgra)
```

---

Alternatively, create a solid alpha layer filled with 128s and merge using OpenCV `merge()`:

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np 
img = cv2.imread('paddington.jpg')

# Create solid alpha layer, same height and width as "img", filled with 128s
alpha = np.full_like(img[...,0], 128)

# Merge new alpha layer onto image with OpenCV "merge()"
bgra = cv2.merge((img,alpha))

# Save result
cv2.imwrite('result.png',bgra)
```

---

Note that, as expected, the OpenCV `cvtColor()` method described first is fastest, by a factor of about 10x because it is hand optimised SIMD code. Timings with given image were as follows:

- `cv2.cvtColor()` - 48 microseconds
- `np.dstack()` - 477 microseconds
- `cv2.merge()` - 489 microseconds

**Keywords**: Python, image, image processing, Numpy, OpenCV, dstack, merge, cvtColor, add alpha channel, add transparency, set transparency, COLOR_BGR2BGRA, cv.COLOR_BGR2BGRA

Comment: I ran the first code  and it works perfectly fine. I am also grateful for the alternative codes, I learned much.