# Set particular channel of Image to certain value according to other image

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv

I have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkYTQ.png) image which has 4 channels. What I want to do is, to reduce this image's opacity. I want the image to remain transparent, however, I just want to reduce the opacity of the VW logo part. (Using opencv/numpy and python)

Here's what I tried :

```
logo = cv2.imread(FILE_PATH, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
logo[:, :, 3] = 50
```

But this assigns the value 50 to all over the image, giving me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hl4G0.png) result. Notice how the remaining part of the image is no more transparent (I want it to remain like the original one.)

I thought of something like:

```
#This is my logic NOT ANY CODE, I want to do something like this:

if (any of) other 3 channels are non zero, make alpha channel of that pixel = 50.
else, keep that pixel as it is. (This pixel would be part of logo)
```

Is there any way of achieving this result, by using opencv / numpy in python? My last option would be to iterate through all the pixels and look for above conditions, but I feel that would be inefficient.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58639332) is exactly what I DON'T want. I want only the logo part(Colored pixels)'s alpha channel to be set to 50.

Comment: logo[(logo[..., :3]!=0).any(2), 3] = 50. For more information see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766757/replacing-numpy-elements-if-condition-is-met)

Answer (score 1):

Just fleshing out the comment from @yann-ziselman...

[image]

Here are the RGBA channels of your image side-by-side, with a red border so you can see the extent on Stack Overflow's background:

[image]

Here's how to do what you ask:

```
import cv2

# Load image including alpha channel
im = cv2.imread('logo.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

# Set alpha channel to 50 anywhere none of the BGR channels is non-zero
im[(im[..., :3]!=0).any(2), 3] = 50

# Save result
cv2.imwrite('result.png', im)
```

**Result**

[image]

**Result split into RGBA channels side-by-side**

[image]