# How can I set the Alpha Channel to 0?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, alpha

I have an RGBA image and I want to set the alpha channel of all white pixels to 0. How can I do that?

Thank you for your help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68646920/set-particular-channel-of-image-to-certain-value-according-to-other-image

Comment: Your question isn't very clear about what should happen to the alpha channel where pixels are not white... should they be set to zero, or 255 or unaffected?

Answer (score 3):

I guess, you're referring to a numpy array.

```py
img_rgb = img[:,:,:3]
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
alpha_mask = img[:,:,-1]
alpha_mask = np.expand_dims(np.where(img_gray ==255, 0, alpha_mask), axis = 2)
img = np.concatenate((img_rgb, alpha_mask), axis = 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you start with this image, wherein the square is transparent and the circle is white:

[image]

You can do this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image, including alpha channel
im = cv2.imread('a.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

# Make a Boolean mask of white pixels, setting it to True wherever all the first three components of a pixel are [255,255,255], and False elsewhere
whitePixels = np.all(im[...,:3] == (255, 255, 255), axis=-1)

# Now set the A channel anywhere the mask is True to zero
im[whitePixels,3] = 0
```

[image]

---

If you want to see the mask of white pixels, do this:

```
cv2.imwrite('result.png', whitePixels*255)
```

[image]

That works because multiplying a False pixel in the Boolean mask by 255 gives zero (i.e. black) and multiplying a True pixel in the mask by 255 gives 255 (i.e. white).